# Carrierwave fog local storage full attachment path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, local, fog

I am building a rails app with carrierwave and fog for attachment storage. In my test environment, I am using fog local storage.

I am looking for a way to get the full attachment path with this configuration.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:               'Local',
    local_root:             '/Users/me/fog',
    endpoint:               '/Users/me/fog',
  }

  config.fog_directory  = 'test.myapp.com
  config.fog_public     = false
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000' }
end
```

When I use any other storage options (like AWS S3), I can get the full url to an attachment just by doing `my_object.my_attachment_url` or `my_object.my_attachment.path`.

However, when using `Local` storage, I only get a relative path to my configuration options like `my_object/my_attachment/1/test.jpg`.

Is there any way through carrierwave or fog to get the full path to this local file?

For my example, the output I am looking for would be: `/Users/me/fog/test.myapp.com/my_object/my_attachment/1/test.jpg`

Answer (score -1):

For me, the answer was modifying to carrierwave uploader class.

I had

```
def store_dir
  "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

which worked fine for AWS S3 as all the S3 specific info was inserted before this string. However, to get this to work with fog `Local` as well, I added:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  def base_path
    "#{File.expand_path(CONFIG.fog_local_root)}/#{CONFIG.fog_directory}/"
  end
else
  def base_path
    ''
  end
end
```